# How to adjust form object transparency

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm looking to determine how I can adjust the transparency of a shape on a Microsoft Access form.  So far I've figured out how to use hWnd to adjust the opacity of the entire form, but I'd like to adjust the opacity of individual form elements/shapes.

This is what I have thus far.  Like I mentioned, it adjusts the entire forms transparency instead of an individual object.

Code on the Form associated with a button:

```
Public Sub FullOpacity_Click()
Dim Transp As Long
Transp = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'This is the color you want your background to be

Me.Detail.BackColor = Transp

Me.Painting = False
SetFormOpacity Me, 0.5, Transp
Me.Painting = True
End Sub
```

Code in a module

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal nIndex As Long, _
   ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal crKey As Long, _
   ByVal bAlpha As Byte, _
   ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const LWA_ALPHA     As Long = &H2

Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE   As Long = -20

Private Const WS_EX_LAYERED As Long = &H80000

Public Sub SetFormOpacity(frm As Form, sngOpacity As Single, TColor As Long)
    Dim lngStyle As Long

    ' get the current window style, then set transparency
    lngStyle = GetWindowLong(frm.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    SetWindowLong frm.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lngStyle Or WS_EX_LAYERED
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes frm.hwnd, TColor, (sngOpacity * 255), LWA_ALPHA
End Sub
```

The object I'm trying to target is called "rectangle" and it's on the form called "Main".

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: AFAIK, Access controls are either opaque or transparent and cannot be semi- either.

Comment: Eh... For one, these functions are labeled `PtrSafe` but not adjusted to actually safely handle 64-bits pointers at all... While this may be possible, it will be very hard, as Access controls do not have unique hWnds, see [this](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0027.htm). You can try focusing individual controls, getting the hWnd, setting the style, repainting the control, but I'd imagine every time it'll get repainted you'd need to reapply the style.